# How can I create a CDF application while using GUIKit?

Tags: cdf-format, gui-construction

I have created a notebook that uses GUIKit to create a user interface.

The targeted user does not have Mathematica available so I thought about using the CDF player to convert the file if possible, because it is available for free download.

I am done with the current stage of the GUIKit app but how can I make it executable for someone without Mathematica?

Comment: GUIKit is largely obsolete since the arrival of version 6 with all the `Dynamic` interactivity stuff. Since we're now at 8 and pretty soon on 9 the question is whether you should invest effort in it. As far as I know CDF player only plays `Manipulate` and `Dynamic` and doesn't do GUIKit.

Comment: When I save it as CDF it simply saves it such that upon opening I see the Mathematica code. Nothing is running or being executed. It's like looking at a PDF of a .nb file.

Comment: This will not work easily. It will be very hard to do. Don't do this. Or at very least don't commit to doing this until you have created a couple of CDFs and are more familiar with the format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that GUIKit is mentioned in [cdf-faq](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/faq/) or in [details for programmers](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/faq/details-for-mathematica-programmers.html), presumably because it is considered obsolete as Sjoerd has mentioned. From the restrictions that are mentioned there (no JLink, no alternative FrontEnds) I would conclude that it isn't supported, although I haven't actually tried whether it works.

There are possibilities to get this running without a full Mathematica license, though: you can either get a Player Pro for your targeted user(s) which will run a GUIKit application or you can contact WRI, as they mention in [cdf-faq](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/faq/) that it is possible to "distribute CDFs with enhanced functionality to people who have the free CDF Player" in collaboration with them...